# htaccess to redirect ANY request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, syntax

two parts....

PART 1 - I want to redirect any request to a directory that DOES NOT exist...
to a it's new location... AND and file that does not exist - to it's new location.

so: myDomain.com/myFolder (which no longer exists)
gets redirected to myDomain.com/newLocation/myFolder

and / or

myDomain.com/myFolder.htm (which does NOT exist)
gets redirected to myDomain.com/newlocation/myFolder

this is close...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^myFolder http://myDomain.com/newLocation/myFolder
```

But I don't necessarily want to TYPE every questionable folder name, I'd prefer to have the 'newLocation" directory checked before the request fails...on any request, not just things i explicitly name

PART 2
Can someone explain the symbols used in the htaccess - or point me to a list...
example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ Rewriterule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/
```

I look at that and I know there are meanings t0 ^/$ etc - smacks of RegEx (not familiar)
 or this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f (what's the !-f mean ????)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d (what's the !-d mean ????)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_var=$1 [L] ( the $1 means ...)
```

I want to understand the symbols and the syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For Part 1 here is the rule will need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
# if requested URI is not a file and not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# externally redirect to /newLocation/{URI}
RewriteRule ^ /newLocation%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

#### For answer to part 2 here is the [Apache mod_rewrite official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)