# How to redirect any request after the first slash using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

i would like to redirect using htaccess to a page that cchecks the query string and sends it to the right page. example http://domain.com/test/one/ gets redirected to http://domain.com/index.php?route=/test/one/ without changing the url structure in the browser or modifying it. I want the htaccess to pick up anything after the first slash and send it to the index.php file.

PS i found this link [htaccess to redirect ANY request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091773/htaccess-to-redirect-any-request) but it modifies the url and throws a 301.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The reason why the other answer is redirecting via a 301 is because the `R=301` flag is in the square brackets of the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: thank you works just fine but just for information purposes what does the flags mean, i know L means last what does QSA mean...thank again

Comment: @VyrenMedia QSA means "Query String Append", See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule under "Flag and Syntax"